# Cloud Build for Appengine and deploy via --imag-url

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Here is my last step which is failing. From the logs, it seems trying to build the service rather using supplied argument `--image-url=blah`. I can see all arguments passed correctly.  Any thoughts what could be reason?

```
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      [
        "app",
        "deploy",
        "cmd/service-api/appengconf/dev/service-api-dev-app.yaml",
        "--image-url=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/service-api:${TAG_NAME}",
      ]
```

after a suggestion I added additional steps to replace `images` however it is still failing.

[image]

actual error `exit code -1`

[image]

Comment: What is the actual error message you're getting when the build step fails?

Comment: @LundinCast added

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the image is unavailable to App Engine... in order to push the image to App Engine, it will need to be present in the registry first. Does your Cloud Build config have a push step, between the build step and the deploy step? If not, you'll probably need to add one (you can't rely on the "[images](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/store-images-artifacts)" field for this, since that pushes the images after all other steps are complete).

So, something like:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: ["build","-t","<foo>","."]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: ["push","-t","<foo>"]
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app","deploy",<etc>]
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging, tinkiring ... I found that for `go111` is supported via `Flex` env only.  Since I really do not need `Flex` at this point  and that feature, not critical rolled back to `standard`.

Answer (score -1):

When deploying your app using a pre-built image, you should only provide the image to the `gcloud app deploy` command, not the app.yaml file, as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#remote-container-build). Your Cloud Build step should rather be:

```
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      [
        "app",
        "deploy",
        "--image-url=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/service-api:${TAG_NAME}",
      ]
```

Comment: I have special setting in `app.yaml` which container depends on. how to handle that?

Comment: btw I tried without `app.yaml` and `cloud-build` complained that the file should be presented.

Comment: You can omit the app.yaml argument if the gcloud command runs from the the folder where the app.yaml file resides. You can specify it in your build step with the "dir" field https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config

Comment: i can give a try.

Comment: `Step #4 - "gcloud-app-deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [/workspace/cmd/service-api/appengconf/dev] could not be identified as a valid source directory or file.`  Though before that step I added `cat that ...app.yaml` so I 100% that path exists.

Comment: A thought: it's probably looking for an exact match to `app.yaml`. Per your config above, your file is named `service-api-dev-app.yaml`. Try renaming it?

Comment: Also, with your image saved in gcr, can you successfully run the `gcloud app deploy path/to/app.yaml --image-url=gcr.io/your-project-id/service-api:your-tag-name` command from your local machine? If not that could be some issue with the `app.yaml` file. Could you show it to us?